# how do you bind the MVC 4 data result of a function to a kendo ui ListView?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-listview

I have the result of a jsonresult method that returns a bunch of data including a list of images.  I'd like to use part of the result (the list of images) to be the datasource for a ListView.  The data comes back from the jsonresult method fine.  If I use alert(data.TravelerImages[x]) in JS, I get back what I expect; however when I try to use data.TravelerImages as a datasource, i seem to get nothing.

The order of operations is as follows:

1. index page loads the view with the jasonresult data populating
   fields - This works.
2. I check that the list of images is populated with correct data -
   this works.
3. I use the list of images as a datasource for the ListView - this
   does not work.

Here is my ListView, notice I set no datasource initially because I can't until the list of images return from the jsonresult method:

```
        <div class="divTraveler_Image">
        @*<img id="TravelerImage" class="Traveler_Image" />*@
        @(Html.Kendo().ListView<DataSourceResult>()
                .Name("lvTravelerImages")
                .TagName("divImageListView")
                .ClientTemplateId("template")
                .Pageable()
                .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(ListViewSelectionMode.Multiple))

            )
        </div>
```

Here's where I am attempting to bind to the ListView (this occurs in the success function of jquery method:

```
 var lvTravelerImageData = new kendo.data.DataSource({ data: data.TravelerImages });

  //alert(data.TravelerImages[0]) // works great

  $('#lvTravelerImages').kendoListView({
       dataSource: lvTravelerImageData,
    });
  lvTravelerImageData.read();
```

This part shows nothing except the empty ListView.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing the ListView for second time instead of getting the client object. You should get the object like follows and use the setDataSource method.

e.g.

```
var lvTravelerImageData = new kendo.data.DataSource({ data: data.TravelerImages });

  //alert(data.TravelerImages[0]) // works great

  $('#lvTravelerImages').data("kendoListView").setDataSource(lvTravelerImageData);

  lvTravelerImageData.read();
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, but then i get travImage undefined (JS error from the kendo template).  Where do i define it at this point?  or how do i set up the template to use the image?

Comment: nevermind, i got it.  brain-dead this early.  I used #:data#.  Thanks so much for the help and the instruction!